# Assigning default values from environment variable in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, default-values

When attempting to set default values for parameters that may exist in *environment variables* in JavaScript, I often see this pattern:

```
var lag;

try {
    lag = process.env.THROTTLE_LAG;
}
catch ( e ) {
    lag = 100;
}
```

I don't like it because, while it follows a common JavaScript pattern of declaring an empty variable for the purpose of later conditionally assigning it a value, the pattern of using try/catch as a *logical branching stratagem* seems kludgey. Examining technical factors, [it tends to perform sub-optimally](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/107727/9492) when compared with other branching strategies. Examining human factors, colleagues have argued that it lacks readability. Of course, [opinions differ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/107818/9492).

This shorter solution uses an empty catch block, which makes me cringe.

```
var lag = 100;

try {
    lag = process.env.THROTTLE_LAG;
}
catch ( e ) {}
```

(I'm open to the idea that my cringe is reflexive and not reflective of a real problem.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `try/catch` for logical branching is not recommended in general, but there are legitimate uses. One example, when you have to query a third party API, and there is no other way to access it. To keep you code more readable, you could encapsulate the try/catch in single, isolated function like

```
 function GetSomethingFromThirdPartyApi(parameter, defaultvalue)
 {
     try
     {
         return ThirdPartyApiCall(parameter);
     }
     catch(e)
     {
         return defaultvalue;
     }
 }
```

In my eyes this function is very clear and concise.

So I recommend to avoid cargo cults like "I have heard that [xyz] is bad, thus I never want to use it" and stay pragmatic - when cleaner alternatives cause more headaches than they prevent, use what works, dogmas don't solve problems.

However, in the given example, you can indeed solve your problem without the use of try catch, by a function like

```
function GetEnvironmentVar(varname, defaultvalue)
{
    var result = process.env[varname];
    if(result!=undefined)
        return result;
    else
        return defaultvalue;
}
```

now you can use it like

```
 var lag = GetEnvironmentVar("THROTTLE_LAG",100);
```

This is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Dogmas don't solve problems, goto does! (Just kidding, excellent answer.)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: I can imagine **a lot** of things [xyz] might stand for, "use of goto" is surely very much on top of that list.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. I like the sentence "use what works, dogmas don't solve problems".

Comment: Avoiding a (likely meritless) cargo cult is precisely why I asked the question; thank you!